# Navigation bar overlays music player in IOS development using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an app that has a music player. The view that is used to select the file to be played contains a navigation bar. The problem is that the navigation bar overlaps the music player interface, preventing me to be able to scroll to the currently playing media. I am using the latest swift, xcode and ios version. Here is a screenshot of the problem and the relevant storyboard region.

[image: app screenshot]

[image: Storyboard]

What I want is to have the navigation bar in the player appear ***above*** the playback navigation controls. Could anybody tell me a way to do that please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` in your viewcontroller.